# how to find basis ' representation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, change-of-basis

I have to prove that there is a representation $L_1:S_3 \to GL_2(F)$ that do this :
$$
L_1((12)) =\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} ,\\
 L_1(1,2,3)=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
I look for a basis , i found in the internet this $e1,e2,e3=-(e1+e2)$ . then I wrote the basis like that :span $\{ (1 0 -1) , (0 1 -1) \}$
thin with this basis i got it that way :
$$
(1,2)( V1-V3)= V2-V3 ,\\
(1,2)( V2-V3)= V1-V3
$$
thats mean:  $L(1,2)= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ its right
$$
 (1,2,3)( V1-V3)= V2-V1 \\
(1,2,3)( V2-V3)= V3-V1
 $$
thats mean : $L(1,2,3)=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and its false :\

I also tried to switch betwen $(1 0 -1) , (0 1 -1)$ and didnt get the correct representation.

can you please help me , were is my fault ? and how I can solve it ?

I'm adding L2 definition:
$L_2:S_3 \to GL_2(F)$

$L_2(1,2)= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$

$L_2(1,2,3)= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$

I have to prove that L1 & L2 are irreducible in any field, I know that in field C if there are two isomorphic representations then they are irreducible but how can we prove that in any field other than C these two representations are irreducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not at all clear what you mean by "I look for a basis", and it's unclear what you're trying to do with all of your work after that.

In order for $L_1$ to define a representation, it must hold that $L_1:S_3 \to GL_2(F)$ is a homomorphism. Because the elements $\sigma := (1\ \ 2\ \ 3)$ and $\tau = (1\ \ 2)$ generate $S_3$, $L_1$ will extend to a homomorphism over $G$ if and only if $L_1(\sigma), L_2(\tau)$ satisfy the relations corresponding to a presentation of $S_3$.  In particular, $S_3$ can be presented as
$$
S_3 = \langle \sigma, \tau \mid \sigma^3 = \tau^2 = (\sigma \tau)^2 = e \rangle.
$$
Thus, in order to prove that $L_1$ defines a representation, it suffices to verify that the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&-1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
satisfy $A^3 = B^2 = (AB)^2 = I$, where $I \in GL_2(F)$ denotes the identity matrix.

Comment: so I can conclude from what you said , that if  proved that A&B satisfy the relations corresponding to a presentation of S3 , its mean that if I show that " A3=B2=(AB)2=I" , I prove that its a representation .

Comment: Yes. The only computation you need to prove that it's a representation is showing that $A^3 = B^2 = (AB)^2$.

Comment: ok  thanks alot for the help i really appriciate it!!

Comment: I forgot to write $\cdots = I$ at the end there. In any case, you're welcome

Comment: @jimmy I don't understand what you mean. If you want to ask about another representation which you're calling $L_2$, I would recommend that you post a new question.

Comment: Yes I edited the post and you can see the modified question.

Comment: The answer is essentially the same.

Comment: I proved that L1 & L2 are Isomorphic if and only if CharIf isnt equal to 3 , How Can also prove that they're irreducible?

Comment: @jimmy Oh, I missed that part. You should post that as a new question. One quick answer is to just use the character of the representations (i.e. the trace)

Comment: I made a new post can you check it please